# SignalR takes a long time to respond to a heartbeat

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, signalr, asp.net-core-signalr

I created a very simple ASP.NET Core app with SignalR with Visual Studio using a Web App MVC application template with the following customization:

- added a reference to @microsoft/signalr library via libman,
- referenced `<script src="~/lib/microsoft-signalr/signalr.min.js"></script>` in `_Layout.cshtml`,
- added the required SignalR services in Startup.cs and created an empty Hub, exposed in the following way:

```cs
            app.UseEndpoints(endpoints =>
            {
                endpoints.MapHub<MyHub>("hub/remote");
                // ... MVC router definitions
            }
```

- created the SignalR connection in JS:

```js
const connection =
    new signalR.HubConnectionBuilder()
        .withUrl("/hub/remote")
        .configureLogging(signalR.LogLevel.Trace)
        .withAutomaticReconnect()
        .build();

connection.start().then(() => console.log("Connected."));
```

Then I launched the MVC app and everything started without an error.
However, I took a closer look at SignalR log messages:

[image: signalr-logs]

I believe this is the SignalR's internal heartbeat that keeps the connection alive.
I wonder why does it take 4-5s between sending the message and receiving the response?

I also tried using SignalR in a more complex application and from time to time I even started receiving "Reconnecting" events, as the load was significantly larger there.

That makes me feel that I do something wrong while configuring the connection, but no idea what exactly.

Comment: "Connection Slow" isn't an event in ASP.NET Core SignalR. And the heartbeats are not directly related to each other, so the gaps are normal.

Comment: Re: Connection Slow - you're right. I got used too much to non-Core SignalR :).
Re: gaps, ok, thanks for confirming that.

Comment: @Brennan looks like there are no other comments. Can you turn your comment into an answer so that I can accept it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

"Connection Slow" isn't an event in ASP.NET Core SignalR.

The heartbeats are not directly related to each other, so the gaps between client and server pings are normal.